# Resizing ubuntu partition in a dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have to resize my ubuntu partition since its running out of space and i am getting warning messages while booting. I searched on internet and got to know that it can be gparted using live CD. I tried that but as the following screenshot shows :

[image]

there is no adjacent empty space for `/dev/sda9` which have ubuntu installed in it and i dont have any idea that what `/dev/sda8` exactly is.

So since it is not possible to resize directly can i first delete `/dev/sda8` and then merge it with `/dev/sda9` and then this can be merged with unallocated space left to `/dev/sda8` and then finally can take some space with `/dev/sda6` to make a bigger ubuntu partition.

or

Is there any other way to do it ? please guide me as i dont want to reinstall ubuntu again with larger space.

Comment: Why don't you check which files you have on that partition (sda8)? Ubuntu should automount it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are only one way to solve it - just simply reinstall Ubuntu deleting everything on your hard drive and all existing partitions. Then install again. You've made too much i think :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinstall Ubuntu on a different partition.Just follow the below steps,

- Boot gparted live-disk and make sure that no partitions are mounted.Before deleting a partition please make a backup of important datas present on that.
- If you don't want the `/dev/sda8` then delete it.It will create a unallocated space of 500 MB.
- To add aditional space to Your Ubuntu partition then you have to resize the `dev/sda6` ntfs partition.For this right-click on the `/dev/sda6` partition and click on *Resize/Move* option.
- After resizing,an unallocated space was created just below to the `/dev/sda6`.
- Then Right-click on the `/dev/sda9` Ubuntu partition and click on Resize/Move option to increase its size by dragging the arrow to the extreme left.